# Is it possible to set default constructor to `std::map<T1, T2>` values?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, std

So I want to create a simple map `std::map<T1, std::string>` and I have a function that returns `std::string` I want somehow to link item creation in std::map with my function so that when `my_map[some_new_element]` is called my function will be called and its return set to value for `some_new_element` key. Is such thing possible and how to do it?

Comment: Certainly possible with some sort of wrapper, but the question is *why*? What's the point of the map? If you only want the fixed value, why not call the function directly?

Comment: Does your function take parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the map itself *or* the value type *or* operator[].

Last wrapper will be the simplest:

```
template <typename T>
std::string& get_default(std::map<T, std::string>& map, const T& key) {
    auto it = map.find(key);
    if (it == map.end()) {
        return map[key] = create_default_value();
    } else {
        return *it;
    }
}
```

The value type shouldn't be too hard, either:

```
struct default_string {
    std::string wrapped_string;
    default_string() : wrapped_string(create_default_value()) {}
    explicit default_string(const std::string& wrapped_string)
        : wrapped_string(wrapped_string) {}
    operator const std::string&() const { return wrapped_string; }
    operator std::string&() { return wrapped_string; }
};
```

Wrapping map will take a bit more work, as you'd have to duplicate the entire interface, including typedefs. Note: this code is not tested, treat it as proof-of-concept, to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: +1 for the `get_default` function, I am not really fond of creating a new type just to force one particular constructor...

Answer (score 2):

What about a small wrapper class for `std::string`?

```
class StringWrapper {

    StringWrapper() { //... your code
    }

    operator std::string&() { return m_string; } // or something like that
private:
    std::string m_string;
};
```

Now you use the following map-type:

```
std::map<T1, StringWrapper> mymap;
```

In the constructor of `StringWrapper` you can define custom actions. It gets called when you insert an item into your map.